# How to list Docker Tags

Tags: docker

I tagged a docker image a couple times using the instructions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_AWSCLI.html#AWSCLI_push_image).  How can I view existing tags I created so far on my docker host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list all your images, including tags:

```
docker images
```

If you're only interested in a particular image, use a name. ex:

```
docker images ubuntu
```